# scalacheck: lift custom random generator

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, scalacheck

Is it possible to lift custom generating function into `Gen`?

For example, generating `ObjectId`s for mongo.

```scala
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId
import org.scalacheck.Gen

val genObjectId: Gen[ObjectId] = Gen.lift(() => new ObjectId)
```

The [only possible solution](https://github.com/hmrc/simple-reactivemongo/blob/master/src/test/scala/uk/gov/hmrc/mongo/json/ReactiveMongoFormatsSpec.scala#L34) I've found is to hack the generator like:

```scala
val genObjectId: Gen[ObjectId] = Gen.numChar.map(_ => new ObjectId)
```

Generating `ObjectId`s using `Gen.hexChar` is irrelevant because:

- I need unique value each time
- Mongo could treat some of the generated hex strings as invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gen.delay(Gen.const(new ObjectId))
```

`delay`'s argument is by-name, so every attempt to generate a value will construct a new `ObjectId`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Moreover, simply `Gen.delay(new ObjectId)` would be enough with `implicit def const[T](x: T): Gen[T]` conversion.